# .Net Find all word offsets in string

Tags: .net, string

I have a string which can contain anything but 99% of the time is a couple of English sentences.

I need to take that string and get a list of indices which represent the start of each word (or to put it another way, at the end of each piece of whitespace). If a definition of white space is required, at a minimum, Space, CR, LF and Period.

What's the simplest way to do this? I assume there's a better way than a `For` loop - I was thinking of using a lambda but I can't see a way to do it that wouldn't be recursive - and that seems like it's begging for a Stack Overflow...

Sample Data:

```
Peter Piper picked a peck
of pickled peppers
```

Desired output is the numbers below. Comments beside to illustrate:

```
6,   'Peter '
12,  'Peter Piper '
19,  'Peter Piper picked '
21,  'Peter Piper picked a '
26,  'Peter Piper picked a peck[CR]'
29,  'Peter Piper picked a peck[CR]of '
37   'Peter Piper picked a peck[CR]of pickled '
```

Comment: I'd go with a simple for loop. You can use linq, but that'd be slower and uglier in this case.

Comment: Example data and desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, incorporating a regular expression *and* a lambda. It may not be the most efficient technique, but it's a nice, declarative one-liner:

```
var indices = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"[^\s\.]+")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(match => match.Index)
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Very elegant - I had to reaward to you.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, better is going to be subjective. Probably better in terms of "ooh wow look I can use a single line of code" but since you need to know the indices of a value, a simple `for` loop would be quick to write, and much easier to maintain.

Given that it's O(n) performance which should be good enough for your case, I'd say just go with a for loop and move on to your next problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following function does what you need without `for` loop. Not sure it's actually shorter though ;)

```
static List<int> FindWordStarts(string sentence, Func<char, bool> is_separator) {

    var indexes = new List<int>();
    bool separator = true;

    sentence.Aggregate(
        0,
        (index, c) => {
            if (is_separator(c))
                separator = true;
            else if (separator) {
                indexes.Add(index);
                separator = false;
            }
            return ++index;
        }
    );

    return indexes;

}
```

Use it like this:

```
string sentence = "Peter Piper picked a peck\rof pickled peppers";
var indexes = FindWordStarts(sentence, c => Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || Char.IsPunctuation(c));
foreach (int index in indexes)
    Console.WriteLine(index);
```

And the result is:

```
0
6
12
19
21
26
29
37
```

Comment: +1 - clean and far more readable than a for loop with state variables all over the place